# Maven Ropository for EWSJavaAPI_1.2.jar

Tags: java, maven, repository, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I work on a project where I use the EWS Java Api to connect to an MS Exchange Server.
To resolve my dependencies I use Maven.

My Problem is that I have to connect to an Exchange Server 2010 SP2 which requires the EWSJavaAPI_1.2.jar but I only found one repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.ewsjavaapi/exchange-ws-api) that contains this EWS Java API.

The problem is that this repository doesn't have the right version.

The newest Version can be download here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5754

But I would like to add this dependency via Maven.

Can you offer me an repository that contains the right version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the EWS-Java-API went [open source](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) it's newest version is now also available in the following maven repository:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/microsoft/ews-java-api/ews-java-api/2.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Lies! The current version is 2.0-SNAPSHOT, and you should never ever ever depend on snapshots.

Comment: @chrispy they released stable version now

Answer (score 7):

I've not found any maven repository with the newest version. What I've done is to install it to the local repository.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=EWSJavaAPI_1.2.jar  -DgroupId=com.microsoft.ewsjavaapi -DartifactId=exchange-ws-api -Dversion=1.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

You may also use maven deploy:deploy-file to add it to a remote repo you have access to;

See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Answer (score 3):

Current version of ews Java api is 2.0

Following is maven information, you can add in your project

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
        <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>oss-sonatype</id>
        <name>oss-sonatype</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Last year they have released stable version. For more details please visit https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/

Comment: According to https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api, "no stable version is available yet, only snapshots in the snapshots repository."

Comment: Now they released stable version. Updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Stable Version of ews-java-api 2.0 has been released:
[Sonatype](https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;gav~com.microsoft.ews-java-api~ews-java-api~2.0~~)

---

[JavaDocs 2.0](http://officedev.github.io/ews-java-api/docs/releases/api-2.0/apidocs/index.html)